# How to cut the background color at the bottom right corner of the text

Tags: javascript, css, border, clip-path

I have issues in cutting the background color at the bottom right corner of the text. is there anyone who can help me ? I manage to make it in Javascript but due to span problem in every word my boss didnt accept my solution so im hoping that there's someone who can help in css without javascript or if theres javascript need to target the id and not span because in sitecore they decide if they want to choose h1, h2, h3 and so on. 
Heres the link:

```css
#bigHeadline,
#smallHeadline{
  display: inline;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    float: left;
}

#bigHeadline{
  -webkit-padding-end: 5%;
    -moz-padding-end: 5%;
    padding-inline-end: 5%;
    font-size: 46px;
    line-height: 58px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    float: left;
    font-weight: 200;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    width: 630px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    font-family: Roboto; 
    font-weight: 200;
  
}
#smallHeadline{
      padding: 0 15px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 33px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: 200;
  
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="c-imagebox-headlines">
      <div class="c-imagebox-headlines-tm-35">
        <h3 id="smallHeadline">Headline 1</h3>
        <br> 
        
        <h1 id="bigHeadline">Once upon a time in the west and east </h1>
        <br> 
        <h2 id="smallHeadline">SAVE <span class="service-texts">Kroner</span>&nbsp;<span>100,-</span> if you book online.</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
      
      
      </body>
    </html>
```

I tried different kind of solution in disabling javascript and use from clip-path, border-radius but I really have difficulties in targeting the bottom right area, please help me.  The red color is the area that I want to clip.

[image]

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Unlikely that you actually want a clip path or anything like that here. Much more likely that you simply want to make the element containing this particular text an _inline_ element, so that its contours follow the text, instead of the whole element creating a _block_.

Comment: Hi @ankit, I tried the solution using Javascript but my boss didn't accept the idea because of the span in every word  heres the link https://jsfiddle.net/vg4z239a/8/#&togetherjs=9vwzFCjxTK

Comment: @misorude I tried the clip path but its cutting the black side from top to bottom I only need to cut the bottom right corner from the east word till end, same as the red color above

Comment: @misorude heres the link,  in my third solution i erase the javascript and im trying to find out how can I clip the background i will appreciate a lot if you can help me.  https://jsfiddle.net/vg4z239a/8/#&togetherjs=9vwzFCjxTK

Comment: I have no clue how that relates to the problem. The black background follows the contours of the text already, so what is wrong with that? What is the _actual_ question here, is this about modifying a given HTML structure that is not suitable to achieve the desired layout via JavaScript, or _what_?

Comment: `#bigHeadline, #smallHeadline{ display:inline; flex-direction: row; float:left; }` - you’re just piling on CSS properties that have rather contrasting or mutually exclusive effects here. Floating cancels out display:inline, and flex-direction makes no sense in that combination either.

Comment: @misorude the solution I made with javascript has a lot of span and it affects the spacing of the headline and my boss didnt accept it, so Im asking help for another solution without javascript

Comment: _Why_ would this need a JavaScript solution to begin with? Where does this HTML output originally _come from_, and why it is not output in a structure more suitable for how you want it to look in the first place?

Comment: @misorude or if theres javascript as long theres no span in every word, I tried to target the div, h1 but theres no luck. So i get back in plain html and css but still my boss wants me to clip the bottom right corner :(

Comment: @misorude because I didnt find any solution to cut the background at the bottom right corner and by using javascript it helps me but unfortunately my boss didnt accept it so im stock again with problem

Comment: Can’t help but feel that you are (massively) over-complicating what could be a really simple thing here. Just make the `#bigHeadline` inline (or add _one single span_ around the whole content of that element, if you need the h1 to stay block for some reason), and then give the background to that inline element … https://jsfiddle.net/7q25udkg/

Comment: @misorude heres the link of my 2nd solution without javascript  https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=73VuRdaowG

Comment: Is the actual problem here that you only want the _last line_ of this to show “inline” behavior, and every line above must go over the full width?

Comment: @misorude thanks for your opinion, I feel bad about it too but I'm still hoping that you can still help me

Comment: The actual problem here is the background in the short text need to cut off  no matter how long the text in the top of it there's only 15px padding  in every end of the headline. It will NOT follow the full width of other text @misorude

Comment: So keeping the 15px padding on both sides of the text along _all_ lines is the problem? That can be fixed using [`box-decoration-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break), see https://jsfiddle.net/7q25udkg/1/ This property has not IE/Edge support yet, but a possible workaround is to fake the padding using a box-shadow instead.

Comment: @misorude your my angel, I salute you thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a simple problem, because you should develop a parser which cuts your string with a `<br/>` in the right way (without cutting a word, or put `<br/>` before a comma/dot/any-simbols). You should get the parent container .c-imagebox-headlines-tm-35's width and then calculate the max amount of word according to the h1's font-size, and make the best approximation of amount of word and font-size.
It's an hard solution for a stupid problem.

Maybe you can try with this thread [Auto-sizing text to fit container](https://discourse.wicg.io/t/auto-sizing-text-to-fit-container/1053)

Comment: Thank you for the link, yes I agree this is not a simple problem, because I already spend a lot of hours for this